# Can an h2 tag be set to a certain percentage of its h1 relative?

Tags: css

I hope this isn't a duplicate; I had a hard time phrasing this while searching for an answer.

I've left my `h1` tags at their default size, and I plan to use `h2` as a sort of subtitle proportionate to whatever `h1` is set to.

I am trying to figure out a way to set `h2` to be a percentage (say, 75%) of whatever `h1` is set to, so that it would auto update if `h1`s size was ever redefined.

```
// an example
h1 {
  font-size:18px;
}

h2 {
  font-size:75% of h1 //obviously not correct
}
```

Comment: Only if they are nested in the html. Otherwise no.

Comment: You could adjust the font size on the container and use EMs to create the relative sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current pure CSS solutions will involve setting the common ancestor element's font-size to be the same as your H1 font size.  Then H1 would be 1em, H2 would be 0.5em (or whatever).  But that would be an inconvenient way to handle it if that ancestor element contains any text other than headlines.

The trivial way to handle it would be with a CSS pre-processor, such as Sass, Less, PostCSS.  Example in Sass:

```
$size: 18px;
h1 {
  font-size: $size;
}
h2 {
  font-size: $size/2;
}
```

A future pure CSS solution will be to use CSS variables, which are currently supported only in Firefox:

```
:root {
    --h1: 20px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: var(--h1);
}

h2 {
    font-size: calc(var(--h1) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Oh - interesting. I know we are using Stylus and Jeet; I'll give this a shot.(I'm quite new to CSS preprocessors)

Comment: Yup - works in Stylus using variables. Not sure why I hadn't thought of that; I guess I was thinking in pure CSS terms.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can set the font-size using `em` units to make them relative to their surroundings, then make each smaller `<hX>` tag 75% smaller than the previous.

```css
h1 { font-size: 2em;     }
h2 { font-size: 1.5em;   }
h3 { font-size: 1.125em; }
h4 { font-size: 0.85em;  }

.sm { font-size: .5em; }
.lg { font-size: 2em;  }
```

```html
<div class="sm"><h1>h1</h1><h2>h2</h2><h3>h3</h3><h4>h4</h4></div>
<h1>h1</h1><h2>h2</h2><h3>h3</h3><h4>h4</h4>
<div class="lg"><h1>h1</h1><h2>h2</h2><h3>h3</h3><h4>h4</h4></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like it would work. The only thing is that it still involves manually keying in a value even if `h1` changes because they aren't really set "relative" to each other. So I might as well just have a `px` value or whatever I was going to use.

Comment: Yeah, it is limited to the extent that CSS itself is limited. Unfortunately, this is as close as you're going to get with pure backwards compatible CSS. And you do realize that using a CSS pre-processor still generates a bunch of fixed sizes in the compiled CSS right?

Comment: Yes. But the pre-processor eliminates the need for me to edit all of the fixed sizes in the compiled CSS, therefore allowing me the flexibility I desired.

Comment: Well, technically, you asked how to do this using CSS, not a CSS preprocessor. If you wanted to know how to do it with a CSS preprocessor then you should have asked as such. As per the current revision, this is the only answer that actually answers the question that was asked.

Comment: I know what you're saying. But the real answer I got from all of this was that pure CSS (at least in browser support terms) doesn't support doing what I wanted to do at this time. A pre-processor does. And I never explicitly stated that pre-processors couldn't be used. In fact, I never used the term "pure CSS" anywhere. I don't mean to be overly argumentative - I just wanted to point that out. I do think that yours was a very useful and well thought out answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you set both as percentages

```
h1 {
    font-size:100%;
}

h2 {
    font-size:75%;
}
```

That way because h1 is 100% then h2 will be 75% of 100%

https://jsfiddle.net/ta5xep3t/

Comment: What is `h1` 100% relative to? I need the regular body font-size to be less.

Comment: 100% is default font size, 200% is double the default font size, it is standard